# Removing auto added product from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I can use this snippet from the woocommerce docs and it works to add a free product when a cart total is reached.  However, our customers need to be able to remove the product from the cart if they don't want it (repeat customers that don't want the same gift every time).  With this snippet, the remove from cart button doesn't work for the free product.

```
/**
 * Add another product depending on the cart total
 */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = 2831; //replace with your product id
        $found = false;
        $cart_total = 30; //replace with your cart total needed to add above item

        if( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total ) {
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                        $found = true;
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            }
        }
    }
}
``
code above is from here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or remove specific cart Item based on WooCommerce cart total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626250/add-or-remove-specific-cart-item-based-on-woocommerce-cart-total)

Comment: This is close @7uc1f3r but this removes once the threshold or free gift requirement is no longer met.  I am looking for ability to remove from cart even if threshold / requirement is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the product from the cart will actually work, but the problem is that the code will also automatically re-add the product again.

One way to solve this would be to remember that the product has already been added once, and to not re-add the product if the product would be added another time (after it has been removed from the cart for example).

A simple way to do that would be to save that data inside of the WooCommerce session, using `WC()->session`. Modified code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = 2831; //replace with your product id
        $found = false;
        $cart_total = 10; //replace with your cart total needed to add above item

        if( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total && ! WC()->session->get( 'free_item_given', false ) ) { // <--- ADDED CHECK FOR free_item_given HERE
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $product_id )
                        $found = true;
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found ) {
                    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
                    WC()->session->set( 'free_item_given', true ); // <--- REMEMBER free_item_given HERE
                }
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
                WC()->session->set( 'free_item_given', true ); // <--- REMEMBER free_item_given HERE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that it solves your problem!

Comment: Yes. This works!  WC()->session is perfect.  thank you!